# Oracle trigger behaviour

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've encounter next problem:
When I'm create new record in table FORMS next trigger starts:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "REA"."AUTOCREATE_TRIGGER" BEFORE
INSERT ON REA.FORMS
FOR each ROW
 WHEN (NEW.LIST_OF_FORMS_ID=59 OR NEW.LIST_OF_FORMS_ID=60) BEGIN
  IF :NEW.LIST_OF_FORMS_ID=59
      THEN   AUTOCREATE.AUTOCREATE_PR340_FR73_S1_T1(:NEW.POWER_FACILITIES_VID, :NEW.ID);
END
```

This trigger call procedure, that create subdocuments and add them in table PR340_FR73_S1_T1. All those subdocuments connected via FORMS_ID with corresponding ID value from table FORMS.

```
    PROCEDURE AUTOCREATE_PR340_FR73_S1_T1(
    POWERFACILITIES NUMBER,
    FORMSID NUMBER) AS
    BEGIN
FOR ROW IN (SELECT VID FROM poe_steam_turbines 
            WHERE POWER_FACILITIES_VID = POWERFACILITIES
            AND IS_ACTUAL = 1) LOOP
INSERT INTO PR340_FR73_S1_T1 (
        HAS_PROLONGATION ----ПРОДЛЕНИЕ
       ,HAS_REMARKING ---ПЕРЕМАРКИРОВКА
       ,HAS_REPLACEMENT --ЗАМЕНА
       ,HAS_REMOVAL --ВЫВОД
       ,POE_STEAM_TURBINES_VID
       ,FORMS_ID
       ) VALUES (
         0
        ,0
        ,0
        ,0
        ,ROW.VID
        ,FORMSID
    );
    END LOOP;
END AUTOCREATE_PR340_FR73_S1_T1;
```

Next trigger starts when record inserts in PR340_FR73_S1_T1 table.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "PR340_FR73_S1_T1_EVENT" BEFORE INSERT ON PR340_FR73_S1_T1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 period NUMBER;
 BEGIN
SELECT PERIOD_ID INTO period FROM FORMS WHERE Id = :NEW.FORMS_ID; -- в этом запросе происходит ошибка из за :NEW.FORMS_ID

  --period:=2016;

   IF :NEW.HAS_REMOVAL = 0
   THEN 
        FILL_EVENT.FILL_REMOVAL_ATR(:NEW.POE_STEAM_TURBINES_VID, period,
        :NEW.STOP_ID, :NEW.REMOVAL_LAST_YEAR);
   END IF;  
END;
```

If I'll define PERIOD with strict value, for example '2016', code works perfectly. But when I'm try to get PERIOD from current new FORMS record - error arise.

Comment: Which error do you receive?

Comment: ORA-04091 table REA.FORMS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Comment: You can't query the table from where the trigger is firing.
So you have to store the value for the period somewhere.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the insert in `AUTOCREATE_PR340_FR73_S1_T1` can be simplified and made much more efficient by getting rid of the `for` loop and doing a simple `insert into .. select`  instead